# Google Glass App disappeared from timeline

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, google-glass

I'm developing a google glass (xe17.3) application with eclipse. Today I accidently cleared the "xml" folder in my project with the "voice_trigger.xml". Then I added the folder and the xml again, but since then my app disappeared from the timeline. It doesn't show any errors and the console says also ".apk installed on device". What can be the problem?

Comment: did you try a "refresh" and "clean" in your eclipse project?

Comment: yes but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you don't see the command in the menu in post XE16 builds it's because either the voice command XML isn't properly formatted (did you manually recreate it?)
Or you might be missing the development permission.

Please post manifest and voice trigger XML..